# Efficiently normalize an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, normalization

I am looking for a way to normalize an array efficiently in C++, Normalization means converting all of your array values into values lower than or equal to n. So this:

`5235 223 1000 40 40`

Becomes:

`4 2 3 1 1` or `3 1 2 0 0`

Here are my codes

```
vector<int> normalize_array(vector<int> arr){
    vector<int> tmp(arr), ret(arr.size());

    sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i){
        vector<int>::iterator iter = find(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), arr[i]);
        ret[i] = std::distance(tmp.begin(), iter);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

The output is `4 2 3 0 0`, the above codes can not handle duplicate elements very well.
Is there any better way to do that?

Comment: this looks like magnitude index not normalization so 1.index sort array, 2. swap values for their index. this is complexity O(N.log(N)) where N is number of values in array. do not think you can be better than that

Comment: the given implementation seem to be O(n^2). making a map between values and indexes probably cut that to O(n log n)

Comment: actually, just replacing `find` with `lower_bound` should do the same.

Comment: also, getting `arr` by value produces an extra vector copy unnecessarily,

Comment: The code doesn't actually produce the desired output (it outputs `4 2 3 0 0`.) Please clarify what transformation you are actually looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Applying tweaks as stated in comments, and using C++ lambdas:

```
vector<int> normalize_array(const vector<int> &arr /* O(1) */) {
    vector<int> tmp(arr) /* O(N) */, ret(arr.size()) /* O(1) */;

    sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.end()); // O(N lg N)

    transform(arr.cbegin(), arr.cend(), ret.begin(), [&tmp](int x) {
        return distance(tmp.begin(), lower_bound(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), x));
    }); // O(N lg N)

    return ret; // O(1) by move semantics
} // O(1) + O(N) + O(1) + O(N lg N) + O(N lg N) == O(N lg N)
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f7c1ca5b1909423)

In the following solution, inspired upon @sachse's answer but using C++11, fixes your problem with correct normalization, to produce `4 2 3 1 1`, as I believe is what is expected:

```
vector<int> normalize_array(const vector<int> &arr) {
    if (arr.empty())
        return {};

    vector<int> idx(arr.size()), ret(arr.size());

    iota(idx.begin(), idx.end(), 0);
    sort(idx.begin(), idx.end(),
         [&arr](int i, int j) { return arr[i] < arr[j]; });

    ret[idx[0]] = 1;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
        ret[idx[i]] = ret[idx[i - 1]] + (arr[idx[i]] != arr[idx[i - 1]]);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d038fb3de613f85b)

Comment: For the provided example, this produces "4 2 3 0 0", while the desired output was "4 2 3 1 1". It's not just a trivial issue with 0 and 1; in general, the code doesn't correctly handle vectors with duplicated values. (Assuming the example is correct, and not the OP's code.)

Comment: A much simpler fix: After `sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());`, insert `auto end = std::unique(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());` and then use `end` instead of `tmp.end()` in the call to `std::lower_bound`. I would have done that, but I thought that `std::map` provides an interesting alternative (although it might be a little slower).

Comment: @rici, second alternative has just a single instance of O(N lg N), and two of O(N). Initial solution, or variation of it, got two instances of O(N lg N), which I believe should make it slower.

Comment: @rici, I've just benchmarked it, and as expected, original solution is twice as slower as the last solution here, and the map based solution is an order of magnitude slower. Tested in 1MB of data: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2cc2cfb5ff74ca68.

Comment: Nice bench. I'm convinced. It's worth nothing, though, that if you change the random number generator to generate vectors with lots of repeats, the balance shifts. (I tried it with `uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 1024);`, which is extreme, so I'm not making any claims here.)

Comment: @rici indeed, good catch, although it seems this last method is always faster, with 1-1024 it beats map slightly, and with 1-10 things get back to the same state as 1-1MB, more or less.

Answer (score 1):

If you define normalization that way (mathematicians would probably say that normalization is something quite different) it becomes a problem of sorting (you are efficiently creating an array of indexes of ascending values). So I guess you should look at sorting algorithms and use them for your case.

You just need to take into account that elements with the same value have the same index - which usually sorting algorithms do not do.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose the following solution which has O(n log n) complexity. The only remaining problem is, that this algorithm does not handle duplicate values with the same normalized value.

```
struct IndexComp {
    IndexComp(const std::vector<int>& vec) : m_vec(vec) {}
    bool operator() (int i,int j) { return (m_vec[i] < m_vec[j]);}
    const std::vector<int>& m_vec;
};

std::vector<int> normalize_array(const std::vector<int>& arr){
    std::vector<int> tmp, ret(arr.size());

    IndexComp indexComp(arr);

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i){
        tmp.push_back(i);
    }

    std::sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), indexComp);

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i){
        ret[tmp[i]] = i;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one `O(n log n)` solution, mostly standard-library based, which handles duplicate values as hinted at by the example in the OP (although it numbers from `0`, rather than `1`, so the example input produces `3 1 2 0 0`:

```
template<typename It, typename OutIt>
void normalize_array(It b, It e, OutIt out) {
  using T = typename It::value_type;
  std::map<T, int> tmp;
  std::transform(b, e, std::inserter(tmp, tmp.begin()),
                 [](T v){ return std::make_pair(v, 0); });
  int i = 0; for (auto& ent : tmp) ent.second = i++;
  std::transform(b, e, out,
                 [&](T v){ return tmp[v]; });
}
```

Rather than sorting directly, it puts all the elements into a temporary map. That sorts them and eliminates duplicates (`O(n log n)`); I could have used a set, but I wanted the map for the next step, which is to number the values in order (`O(n)`). Then the map can be used to lookup the index for each value. (`O(n log n)`).

While the solution is optimal in terms of complexity, there are probably ways to get the constants down.

See it live on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d74a97f4f8029a75)

Comment: adding map to the problem adds non-contiguous memory access (node-based data structure), which **may** not be cache friendly. Even though something resembling the original vector based solution contains O duplicates, it seems more cache friendly, which is a important matter since OP asks for real performance, not only theorical.